# RabbitMQ support for LIFO or time based priority queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

Is there any way to make a RabbitMQ queue behave as a Stack, i.e. the client gets the last message that was posted in the queue (LIFO) rather than the first one? Or maybe alternatively make it a priority queue using a timestamp which the client could set?

RabbitMQ does support priority queues but the priority it allows is just a number up to 255 (recommended to use up to 10).

What I want to achieve is that the latest messages are processed first because they contain the latest information about the source. I still want to process the old messages, but in situations when the client cannot keep up (or there was some downtime and the client is recovering) I want to process the latest state information first.

The only solution I came up with so far is to use a TTL on the messages of the main queue and have them go to a dead letter queue when they expire, which is also processed by the client. However this is not so clean, and if the source of the message takes longer than the TTL to send a new status update, the latest state will be stuck in queue behind the other older expired messages still to be processed.

If it is not possible to achieve with RabbitMQ, is there any other recommended messaging framework that supports this requirement?

Comment: Not sure what the exact use case is , however you can try to limit the queue length to a very small number ( ideally 1 ) and have multiple queues where each queue handles a very specific event , in that case the only message in the queue will be the one with most recent information about a particular event/source.

Comment: Don't know if you count Redis among _messaging frameworks_, but it should do with `RPUSH`/`LPUSH` and `RPOP`/`LPOP`.

Comment: @TomášLinhart I haven't explored Redis yet, will have a look at it

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee Imagine you have sensors reporting data like temperature, position etc. all of these are sending data every few seconds with timestamp included (so out of order processing is OK). I can't set the queue length to just 1, there are thousands of sensors and I still want to process all messages. But I just want the latest one to be in front of the queue to have the current status as fast as possible rather than have to process all the older messages to arrive to my current state of the world.

Comment: What is "processing" consisting of? Typically, it is not valid to process messages out of order to arrive at a state. Alternatively, if each message carries the entire state, then what processing needs to take place?

Comment: @theMayer Processing consists of updating a few tables in a database related to the specific asset (sensor etc.). By "typically" you must mean in your limited exposure. I have seen several systems where out of order processing is perfectly valid. In fact, if you have multiple clients connected to a RabbitMQ queue the consumption order becomes arbitrary. If your messages are carrying a timestamp or a sequence number reconstructing order is trivial. Yes the message coming from an asset carries the whole state, it needs to be stored somewhere for display, reports and some further logic etc.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka [Log Compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) was created for exactly the use case you describe:

> Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last
>   known value for each message key within the log of data for a single
>   topic partition. It addresses use cases and scenarios such as
>   restoring state after application crashes or system failure, or
>   reloading caches after application restarts during operational
>   maintenance. Let's dive into these use cases in more detail and then
>   describe how compaction works.

Comment: But won't Log Compaction delete old messages? I still want to keep them, they are important for other aspects of the system. I just want to process the latest first for each sensor (source).

Comment: Another option is to not use a messaging system, but something like Cadence Workflow (cadenceworkflow.io) which gives you full control over processing order and much more.

Answer (score 1):

So, RabbitMQ is a *queue*, not a *stack*.  It is specifically designed NOT to do what you are asking (a queue is always a first-in, first-out data structure).

However, there are options:

1. Presumably some process (e.g. a web service) exists between the client and the message server. This process could save the data off to an additional storage location (e.g. [memcached](https://memcached.org/)) for immediate access of the latest value, thus leaving the queue untouched.
2. You could configure a secondary queue/service combination. When messages are published, they can then be routed to both queues. The first queue is for your heavy processing, and the second queue would be a service whose only task is to update the latest value in memcached or some other fast storage/retrieval system.  Thus, message lifetime in this queue would presumably be much shorter.
3. You could implement multiple processing steps. The first step would be to update the current state (presumably a quick operation), after which the message is then re-published to the longer processing step's queue.

Comment: Well RabbitMQ is really a message broker. It has priority queues which are not FIFO. It also has a lot of other functionality (exchanges, intelligent routing, fan out, etc.) so your opening statement is a bit too simplistic. Option 1 defeats the whole point, you want the entry to the system to be lightweight and then queued. Option 2 is similar to what I mentioned with 2 queues, with a TTL on the first and dead lettering to the second. Not sure what you meant by option 3, what state are you talking about? If the current state in the DB was updated then there is no problem.

Comment: @jbx - you don't seem to have a very good idea of what you need and why you need it. I understand RabbitMQ has other features. I disagree with the addition of "priority queues" (it was a late add), but it is part of the AMQP specification. Beyond that, it's up to you to clearly define the issue. RabbitMQ is not a database server, it is a message queue. If your database is so slow that messages are queuing up awaiting a basic `save` operation, then you have a major problem there. Go there to solve it.

Comment: I have a very clear idea of what I want. I am asking if it is possible with RabbitMQ or with another message broker. If in your world systems do not fail, then you have never developed a real system, because systems fail, and when they fail, messages queue up. It is such a common requirement in fact that Kafka has something similar for these cases, as indicated in another answer, just not exactly what I need.